# How can I programmatically create a list of objects of the leaflet icon class?

Tags: r, r-leaflet

How can I programmatically create a list of objects of the leaflet icon class?

I have created a map using the `leaflet` library that will eventually show dozens of locations. For this I want to add some custom icons using the `addMarkers` function, which takes an `iconSet` created using `iconList` as documented [here](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html).

In the example below (which uses icons from https://icon-library.net/), the creation of `myicons` by means of `iconList`, which contains two direct calls to `makeIcon`, is unproblematic because only two icons are used. However, in the real world the number of icons, their URLs and other attributes will not be known in advance.

If create a list using `iconList` and use `cbind` to attach it to the data frame as a new column, I get the expected "cannot coerce class" error message.

My only option appears to be to programmatically create the `myicons` list, but using something like `mynewicons <- iconList(sapply(1:nrow(df.data), function(i) {makeIcon(df.data$url[i],iconWidth = df.data$width[i],iconHeight = df.data$height[i])}))` results in an `Arguments passed to iconList() must be icon objects returned from makeIcon()` error.

How can I create this list of leaflet icons dynamically rather than specifying it in advance?

```r
require(leaflet)
require(magrittr)

entrynames <- c("Entry 1","Entry 2")
lat <- c(51.509950,51.510736)
lng <- c(-0.1345093,-0.135190)
iconurl <- c("https://icon-library.net/images/right-arrow-icon-png/right-arrow-icon-png-9.jpg",
                "https://icon-library.net/images/back_previous_arrow_play_next_stop_pause_101040.png")
iconwidth <- c(60,50)
iconheight <- c(60,50)
df.data <- data.frame(entrynames=entrynames,lat=lat,lng=lng,
                      url=iconurl,width=iconwidth,height=iconheight,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df.data$entrynames <- as.character(df.data$entrynames)

myicons <- iconList(
    marker1 = makeIcon(iconUrl = df.data$url[1],iconWidth = df.data$width[1],iconHeight = df.data$height[1]),
    marker2 = makeIcon(iconUrl = df.data$url[2],iconWidth = df.data$width[2],iconHeight = df.data$height[2])
)

m <- leaflet() %>% setView(lng = -0.1345093, lat = 51.510090, zoom = 18) %>% addTiles() %>%
    addMarkers(data = df.data,
               lat = ~lat,
               lng = ~lng,
               icon = myicons)
m
```

MRE output:

[image: Custom markers in leaflet for R]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit hacky and I am not too familiar with leaflet but using `purrr::map` and `purrr::flatten` plus fixing names and attributes seems to work:

```r
require(leaflet)
#> Indlæser krævet pakke: leaflet
require(magrittr)
#> Indlæser krævet pakke: magrittr

entrynames <- c("Entry 1","Entry 2")
lat <- c(51.509950,51.510736)
lng <- c(-0.1345093,-0.135190)
iconurl <- c("https://icon-library.net/images/right-arrow-icon-png/right-arrow-icon-png-9.jpg",
             "https://icon-library.net/images/back_previous_arrow_play_next_stop_pause_101040.png")
iconwidth <- c(60,50)
iconheight <- c(60,50)
df.data <- data.frame(entrynames=entrynames,lat=lat,lng=lng,
                      url=iconurl,width=iconwidth,height=iconheight,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df.data$entrynames <- as.character(df.data$entrynames)

myicons <- iconList(
  marker1 = makeIcon(iconUrl = df.data$url[1],iconWidth = df.data$width[1],iconHeight = df.data$height[1]),
  marker2 = makeIcon(iconUrl = df.data$url[2],iconWidth = df.data$width[2],iconHeight = df.data$height[2])
)

mynewicons <- purrr::map(1:nrow(df.data), 
                         function(i) {
                           iconList(makeIcon(df.data$url[i],
                                             iconWidth = df.data$width[i],
                                             iconHeight = df.data$height[i])
                                    )
                           }
                         ) %>% 
  purrr::flatten()
names(mynewicons) <- glue::glue("marker{1:nrow(df.data)}")
attr(mynewicons, "class") <-  "leaflet_icon_set"
identical(myicons, mynewicons)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I'll take hacky if it works - and it seems to. Thanks.

Comment: brilliant usage of purrr mapping